# dynamic change endpoint camel

Tags: dynamic, apache-camel, endpoint

Is it possible to change from endpoint in dynamic way ?
for example I want change

```
for(endpointFirst).routeId(ROUTEID).to(finishEndpoint);
```

to

```
for(endpointSecond).routeId(ROUTEID).to(finishEndpoint);
```

I try use

```
camelContext.stopRoute(TestRoute.ROUTEID);
```

change old endpoint to new endpoint

```
camelContext.startRoute(TestRoute.ROUTEID);
```

but my efforts not work properly.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to

1. stop the route
2. remove the route
3. change the endpoint
4. add the route
5. start the route

This allows you to change the from endpoint to whatever you want (for example something else)

Some components / endpoint do allow to change options an have those being updated at runtime. For example the JMS endpoint allows this, so you can

1. stop the route
2. change an option on the jms endpoint
3. start the route

But there may be some components which cannot do that.

Comment: Could you please point where I can find an example for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to change the `from` endpoint, you can just dynamically add/remove routes via the context APIs or alter the route as Claus suggested

to change destination endpoints, use the [recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) EIP and an Expression to dynamically determine the endpoint based on message headers, variables, methods, etc...

```
from("direct:a")
     .recipientList(header("foo"));
```

Comment: I know pattern recipientList but I want change first endpoint - from , so in case I can't use recipientList.