# Apache Camel File Component dynamic source directory in from EndPoint

Tags: apache-camel

I am currently working on a Camel based test harness application, that processes groups of files from multiple folders and compares with the files present in the local repository.

Is there any way to change the folder location from the end point in Camel route dynamically? I want to use a single route for polling files from the multiple folders.

Answer (score 0):

According [dynamic change endpoint camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248776/dynamic-change-endpoint-camel), use following procedure:

1. stop the route
2. remove the route
3. change the endpoint
4. add the route
5. start the route