# SFTP download from dynamic directories using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

On a same SFTP location, there are day wise structure as bellow.

- 2014/06/29/
- 2014/06/30/
- 2014/07/01/
- 2014/07/02/

Folowing route is working fine and each 30S the consumer checks the SFTP location and downloads .txt files.

```
from("sftp://user@host?antInclude=*/*/*/*.txt"
                + "&password=xxx" + "&recursive=true" + "&idempotent=true"
                + "&scheduler=spring&scheduler.cron=0/30+*+*+*+*+?")
            .to("file:/home/user/data");
```

But above route will scan ALL the directories in the SFTP location and it MAY be a performance issue. So I need to scan only for today and previous day like bellow.

```
from("sftp://user@host?antInclude=2014/07/03/*.txt,2014/07/02/*.txt"
                + "&password=xxx" + "&recursive=true" + "&idempotent=true"
                + "&scheduler=spring&scheduler.cron=0/30+*+*+*+*+?")
            .to("file:/home/user/data");
```

But, I need to use dynamic directory pattern for `antInclude=` option. I am trying with several approaches but it was not success. Can you please give me an idea with your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source endpoint is not dynamic. If you need to change it, process as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713711/how-to-update-camel-properties-externally/23719221#23719221). So, one possible solution could be to use a scheduler to update the route every day. Not very elegant, I know.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. 
Isn't it possible to use 'PollingConsumerPollStrategy' to do that?

Comment: `PollingConsumerPollStrategy` is used e.g. for rolling back the processing when something goes wrong. I don't see that this could be helpful for you.

Comment: You may accept the answer and upvote it if it helped you, so that everybody sees that the question has been answered.