# Apache Camel - Build both from and to endpoints dynamically

Tags: apache, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, endpoint

I have a camel route which processes a message from a `process queue` and sends it to `upload queue`.

```java
from("activemq:queue:process" ).routeId("activemq_processqueue")
        .process(exchange -> {
            SomeImpl impl = new SomeImpl();
            impl.process(exchange);
        })
        .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "activemq:queue:upload");
```

In `impl.process` I am populating an `Id` and `destination server path`. Now I need to define a new route which consumes messages from upload queue ,and copy a local folder (based on Id generated in previous route) and upload it to destination folder which is an ftp server (this is also populated in previous route)

So how to design a new route where both from and to endpoints are dynamic which would look something like below ?

```java
from("activemq:queue:upload" )
        .from("file:basePath/"+{idFromExchangeObject})
    .to("ftp:"+{serverIpFromExchangeObject}+"/"+{pathFromExchangeObject});
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15254698/86798

Comment: is it ? Thanks @Mr Gravity I'll still do some research though !

Comment: VG Hedge - In the question you linked to, Claus also replied that that issue has been fixed.

Comment: you can use the `.toD()` to specify a dynamic Camel endpoint 

http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: @Mike Barlotta Thank you. That explains how to form dynamic to () endpoint. Now how to form dynamic from() endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a better alternative for your case, taking as granted that you are using a Camel version newer than 2.16.(alternatives for a previous version exist but the are more complicated and don't look elegant - ( e.g consumerTemplate & recipientList).

You can replace the first "dynamic from" with pollEnrich which enriches the message using a polling consumer and simple expression to build the dynamic file endpoint. For the second part, as already mentioned, a dynamic uri .toD  will do the job. So your route would look like this:

```
 from("activemq:queue:upload" )
    .pollEnrich().simple("file:basePath/${header.idFromExchangeObject})
    .aggregationStrategy(new ExampleAggregationStrategy()) // * see explanation 
    .timeout(2000) // the timeout is optional but recommended
    .toD("ftp:${header.serverIpFromExchangeObject}/${header.pathFromExchangeObject}")
```

1. See content enricher section "Using dynamic uris"
   http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html .

   You will need an aggregation strategy, to combine the original exchange with the resource exchange in order to make sure that the headers serverIpFromExchangeObject, pathFromExchangeObject will be included in the aggregated exchange after the enrichment. If you don't include the custom strategy then Camel will by default use the body obtained from the resource. Have a look at the ExampleAggregationStrategy example in content-enricher.html to see how this works.
2. For the .toD() have a look at http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thank you so much @ltsallas. This is what I was looking for. And it worked  :) I've couple of questions :
1. In aggregation strategy, I'm just setting required headers from oldExchange to newExchange and returning newExchange and nothing else. Is this fine?
2. Since we're adding routes dynamically based on varying parameters, should we delete the routes manually?

Comment: @vg-hegde 1. Yes this is fine. You can do whatever you like in an aggregation strategy. Its up to your requirements. 2. I do not quite understand the second question. Where did you add routes dynamically?

Comment: sorry I had forgot to reply ! . "adding routes dynamically" I meant it for the other answer provided by Mike Barlotta

Comment: @VGHegde I saw your newer related question. My example does not work with the recursive option. pollEnrich does not support batch operations :(. So probably a dynamic route is your best option unless you can  1) zip folder before polling. 2) poll the compressed folder(one file). 3) ftp the compressed file(advantage of smaller transfer size if the contents of the folders weren't compressed) 4) extract folders remotely using ssh- don't know if this is possible!. I tried that locally. Check  here an example https://gist.github.com/ltsallas/6096624aed65ce06bb65c86add125c75#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Thank you so much. For others - related question is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103035/apache-camel-pollenrich-is-not-copying-all-the-files/38112160#38112160)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a dynamic to endpoint in Camel (as noted in the comment) can be done with the `.toD()` which is described [on this page on the Camel site.](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) 
I don't know of any `fromD()` equivalent. However, you could add a dynamic route by calling the `addRoutes` method on the `CamelContext`. This is described on [this page on the Camel site.](http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html)

Expanding slightly on the example from the Camel site here is something that should get you heading in the right direction.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
   String idFromExchangeObject = ...
   String serverIpFromExchangeObject = ...
   String pathFromExchangeObject = ...

   exchange.getContext().addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
       public void configure() {
           from("file:basePath/"+ idFromExchangeObject)
            .to("ftp:"+ serverIpFromExchangeObject +"/"+pathFromExchangeObject);
       }
   });
}
```

There may be other options in Camel as well since this framework has an amazing number of EIP and capabilities.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike Barlotta . This solution worked too :)