# Apache Camel pollEnrich is not copying all the files

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, endpoint

I've a camel route which looks like below

```java
from("activemq:queue:upload" )
    .pollEnrich().simple("file:basePath/${header.ID}?noop=true&recursive=true")
    .aggregationStrategy(new ExampleAggregationStrategy()) 
    .timeout(2000) 
 .toD("ftp:${header.destinationURI}")
```

In my file system `file:basePath/${header.ID}` contains multiple folders. When above route is executed, only 1st file from the 1st folder will be copied to ftp server. Remaining folders(with subfolders) aren't getting copied to ftp server!

And `ExampleAggregationStrategy()` class's `aggregate()` method looks like below

```java
@Override
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            String destinationURI = "populatedURI";

        oldExchange.setOut(newExchange.getIn());
        oldExchange.getOut().setHeader("ID",  oldExchange.getIn().getHeader("ID"));
        oldExchange.getOut().setHeader("destinationURI", destinationURI);
        oldExchange.setFromEndpoint(newExchange.getFromEndpoint());
        oldExchange.setFromRouteId(newExchange.getFromRouteId());

            return oldExchange;
        }
```

I've tried setting `properties and onCompletions` as well. Still no luck !
Am I missing anything in `aggregationStrategy` ?
How to copy all the files and folders successfully using `pollEnrich`?

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question but I had similar problem and I solve it using `loopDoWhile()`. Here's my route:

```
from("direct:start")    
    .setProperty("StartDate", simple("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss}"))
    .to("direct:download");

from("direct:download")
    .loopDoWhile(body().isNotNull())
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple("sftp://{{remote.user}}@{{remote.url}}/{{remote.directory}}?password={{remote.password}}"
                + "&move=.done/${property.StartDate}"
                + "&localWorkDirectory=work/tmp"
                + "&autoCreate=false"
                + "&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true"
                + "&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true"
                + "&recursive=true"
        )
        .timeout(0)
        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
                .to("file:work/inbox/?fileName=${file:name}")
            .otherwise()
                .end()
    .end();
```

I hope it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 4):

pollEnrich always works with single file. The intention behind this is get the content from endpoint (A) and then get content from poller enrich (B) and then we aggregate this two content and write it to other endpoint.

In your case A would be from("activemq:queue:upload" ) body and B would be ("file:basePath/${header.ID}?noop=true&recursive=true") . If it finds multiple files , it selects only one file and you can play around aggregator and write it to FTP.

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any way I can handle above scenario where I want to copy all the files(With folders) for each message in the queue ?

Comment: My requirement is posted here [apache-camel-build-both-from-and-to-endpoints-dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839725/apache-camel-build-both-from-and-to-endpoints-dynamically)

Comment: Are the folders known in advance or dynamic based on the message in the queue?

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti Folder names are known dynamically based on the message in the queue.

Comment: Can you give an example of a path that will be put in the header?

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti  ID and Destination URI are put in the header. Later based on that ID (which we will pick from the message coming from queue) we form the path : example : `simple("file:c//test//source/"+"ID12345"?noop=true&recursive=true")` and `.toD("ftp://userName:password@10.10.10.192//test/destination/"+"ID12345")`