# consume all files in Apache Camel pollEnrich

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

Is there any way or property in `pollEnrich` which helps us to consume all files at once? I can't use `from` because it's already being used for timer. 2 `from` are not allowed in a single route.

Here is my code:

```
from("timer://foo")
.pollEnrich("file:src")
.aggregate(new ZipAggregationStrategy()).constant(false)
.completionFromBatchConsumer().eagerCheckCompletion()
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("file"+".zip"))
.to("file:src/test/java/out");
```

I want the all files in src to be zipped in a folder. But `pollEnrich` is consuming file one at a time, which is causing problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Camel pollEnrich is not copying all the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103035/apache-camel-pollenrich-is-not-copying-all-the-files)

Comment: completionFromBatchConsumer won't work because you're not using the file component as the consumer. The solution is to repeat the pollEnrich call until it returns a null body. See comment above with link to this question and answer.