# WMQ Integration using ApacheCamel

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying post and get messages to remote WMQ using camel. There are 2 Queues i.e Request and Response Queue. i am able to post to Response Queue using my camel routes. but there are certain headers need to set to post to Request Queue. 
I am facing issue while posting to Request Queue.

i have a working copy of java code which able to post to both queues and get the data. But i need my camel route to do that.

Here i am attaching code snippet of both java(Working) and camel one.
can some one help on this it would be great help for me.

is it mandatory to set **MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();**

and

**int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT;**

if so how to set these parameters using camel.

as shown in below code?

**java code**

```
 public class GskMQMessage extends MQMessage
    public void connect() {
        MQException.log = null;
        int openOptions = 0;
        try {
            Hashtable mqKeyValueProps = new Hashtable();
            //com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC
            mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, portNo);
            mqKeyValueProps.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
            if (queueMgr_ == null) {
                queueMgr_ = new MQQueueManager(queueMgrName_, mqKeyValueProps);
            }

            mqTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (sendQueue == null) {
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT;

                sendQueue = queueMgr_.accessQueue(sendQueueName_, openOptions);
            }

            if (this.sendMqMessage_ == null) {
                this.sendMqMessage_ = new GskMQMessage();
            }

        }
    } catch (MQException mqEx) {
        mqEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    public String mqPut(String callPhase, byte[] byteControlHeader, String sendMessageText) {

        long mqTime = 0;
        String recvData = "";
        this.sendMqMessage_.characterSet = 943;
        this.sendMqMessage_.expiry = 300;
        this.sendMqMessage_.persistence = MQC.MQPER_NOT_PERSISTENT;
        this.sendMqMessage_.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
        byte[] byteApplIdData = //32 byte id
            this.sendMqMessage_.applicationIdData = new String(byteApplIdData);
        this.sendMqMessage_.messageId[i] = //24 byte id
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        pmo.options = MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT;
        this.sendMqMessage_.clearMessage();

   //write to MQMessage.
      this.sendMqMessage_.write(byteControlHeader);
        this.sendMqMessage_.write(sendMessageText.getBytes(System.getProperty("file.encoding")));
        mqTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //put message to WMQ
        this.sendQueue_.put(this.sendMqMessage_, pmo);
    }
```

**Camel Code:**

Not able to post to Request Queue Even though set Headers as in the code. please let me know what is issue in the below code.

```
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message message = exchange.getIn();
        String wmqHost = (String) message.getHeader(HOST);
        int mqPort = Integer.parseInt((String) message.getHeader(PORT));
        String queueMngr = (String) message.getHeader(QUEUE_MNGR);
        String channel = (String) message.getHeader(CHANNEL);
        String sendQueue = (String) message.getHeader(SEND_QUEUE);
        String receiveQueue = (String) message.getHeader(RECEIVE_QUEUE);

        String connName = queueMngr + channel;

        //setting IBM MQ Specific Headers
        message.setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_APPLIDENTITYDATA,
            appIdententyData());
        message.setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_MSGID, createMsgId());
        message.setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_CORRELID, MQC.MQCI_NONE);
        message.setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_PERSISTENCE,
            MQC.MQPER_NOT_PERSISTENT);
        message.setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_EXPIRY, new Integer("300"));
        message.setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_CODEDCHARSETID,
            new Integer("943"));
        message.setBody(getSeriesStartBody());
        CamelContext camelContext = //getting context;
            if (camelContext.getComponent(connName) == null) {
                validateWMQParams(wmqHost, mqPort, channel, queueMngr);
                camelContext.addComponent(connName, JmsComponent
                    .jmsComponent(createWMQConnection(wmqHost, mqPort,
                        queueMngr, channel)));
            }
    }

    //creates connection with wmq
    private com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory createWMQConnection(String host,
        int port, String queueMngr, String channel) throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        mqConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueMngr);
        mqConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
        return mqConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please update your question with any exception details. I have a sample here https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-camel/blob/master/simplesample/src/main/java/camel/wmq/samples/MFTStats.java - if that helps

Comment: http://lowry-techie.blogspot.se/2010/11/camel-integration-with-websphere-mq.html

Comment: It would help to include the error details as Shashi says. If your WMQ endpoint/component is not dynamic then don't set it within the processor. Define it when the camel context is initially created. Camel routes need to be stopped and started if you modify the options of endpoints/components. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15254698/86798)

Comment: Sorry for responding late..@Shashi  i cant see the error logs since it is an GDS system.i saw your example but that is also not working in my case. it is ok for simple plain text but in my case there are certain headers as i mentioned in the java program. Suggest me how can i set MQPutMessageOptions, MQGetMessageOptions and open option to Queue using camel. if i miss the above even my java program is not able to post message to queue. and point me if any article explains how camel body and header value will set MQMessage.